# Mount a linux_raid_member (level 1)

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

**Original topic:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78804/how-to-mount-a-disk-from-destroyed-raid-system

> I did it by the "hard way": (first if its possible clone this disk
>   before you do anything!)
>
> dmesg for the raid-disk or try (example: sdc1)
>
> `$ fdisk -l`
>
> Change the RAID-DISK-Flag to your Linux filesystem (ext3 or
>   something), save this and reboot.
>
> After that
>
> `$ mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdx`
>
> and voila you can mount
>
> `$ mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`

After following these steps and zerooing the superblock I got the following - using RAID level 1:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/# mount /dev/sdc /mnt/sample/
root@ubuntu-server:/# mount: /mnt/sample: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Things that I didn't fully understand:

- How can you change the RAID disk flag?
- Is that really possible to mount a single disk without a superblock and using mdadm?

Comment: What does `sudo file -sL /dev/sdc` report? was the whole device a raid member, or was it originally partitioned?

Comment: Yes, the whole device was a raid member.

`root@ubuntu-server:/# file -sL /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: data`

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this: Don't mess with the disk! Stop the existing raid and create a new one using `mdadm` as outlined in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78804/how-to-mount-a-disk-from-destroyed-raid-system